# $x^2 - (m - 2)x + 6 = 0$ : Possible values of $m$.

Tags: contest-math, quadratics

> One of the roots of the equation $x^2 - (m - 2)x + 6 = 0$ lies between
> $(0, 2)$ and the other root lies between $(3, 4)$. It is known that
> $m$ is an integer. What is the sum of all the possible values of $m$?

Let $a$ be the root that lies between $(0, 2)$ and let $b$ be the root that lies between $(3, 4)$. I can write it mathematically as
$0 \lt a \lt2$ and $3 \lt b \lt4$ and also we can say that $3 \lt a+b \lt6$.

$a+b=m-2$ and this means that $3 \lt m-2 \lt6 \Rightarrow 5 \lt m \lt 8$. So the possible integer values of $m$ should be $6$ and $7$ and the possible sum should be $13$.

But as per the solution this is not the correct answer. What have I done wrong? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: If m is 7 then the roots are 3 and 2.

Comment: $3 \lt a+b \lt 6$ is a necessary condition, but it is not a sufficient one. If $a+b = 4$ for example, the roots are not even real.

Comment: @dxiv : Then what should be the other necessary condition? How can we solve this? I am not able to think in other ways.

Comment: @Ganit You only got two candidate values for $m$. It's easiest to just substitute each one back into the equation and check whether it works.

Comment: It’s given that the equation has 2 roots so you may also use the discriminant condition to get the other restriction on m. Or substitute the values of m (there are only two)  that you got in the equation to see if they work.

Answer (score 2):

**No real root is possible for integral $m$ in (0,2) and (3,4)**

Let $f(x)=x^2-(m-2)x+6$. $f(0)=6>0$, then for a root in (0,2) we should have $f(2))<0 \implies 14-2m<0 \implies m>7$.

Next for a root in (3,4), $f(3)=9-3(m-2)+6=21-3m<0$, next we demand $f(4)>0 \implies 16-4(m-2)+6>0\implies m<7.5$. Hence no integral value of $m$ is possible.

For $m=7$ the roots are 2 and 3. For $7 <m<7.5$, roots lie in (0,2) and (3,4).Hence, no real root is possible for integral m in (0,2) and (3,4).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using Viete's relations the way you did for the inequality is that they apply even when the roots are complex.  So $ \ x^2 - (6-2)x + 6 \ = \ 0 \ $ has the roots $ \ 2 \ \pm \ i\sqrt2 \ \ , $ which sum to $ \ 4 \ \  \ , $ satisfying $ \ 3 \ < \ a+b \ < \ 6 \ \ . $

One way we can look at the quadratic polynomial is to consider its "vertex form" describing an "upward-opening" parabola with $ \ y-$intercept $ \ (0 \ , \ 6 ) \ \ . $  "Completing the square" produces
$$ x^2 \ - \ (m-2)x \ + \ 6 \ \ = \ \ \left(x \ - \ \frac{m-2}{2} \right)^2 \ + \ \left(6 \ - \ \frac{(m-2)^2}{4} \right) \ \ , $$
which tells us that the vertex is the $ \ x-$intercept of the parabola for
$$  6 \ - \ \frac{(m-2)^2}{4}  \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ m \ \ = \ \ 2 \ \pm \ 2·\sqrt6 \ \ . $$

Our quadratic equation then has real roots for $ \   m \  <   \ 2 \ - \ 2·\sqrt6 \   $ and $ \   m \  >   \ 2 \ + \ 2·\sqrt6 \ \ .  $  *But* the $ \ y-$intercept at $ \ (0 \ ,  \ 6 ) $ means that we cannot has *positive* real roots for $ \   m \  <   \ 2 \ - \ 2·\sqrt6 \  \ ,  $ since the vertex is "to the left" of the $ \ y-$axis, leaving us with $ \   m \  >   \  \approx \ 6.899 \ \ .  $

With $ \ m \ $ required to be an integer, we can assess cases directly.  For $ \ m \ = \ 7 \ \ , $ the equation is $ \ x^2 - (7-2)x + 6 \ = \ (x-2)·(x-3) \ = \ 0 \ \ ; $ unfortunately, neither of the roots are in the specified *open* intervals.  The next integer case leads to  $ \ x^2 - (8-2)x + 6 \ = \  0 \ \ , $ with roots $ \ 3 - \sqrt3 \ \approx \ 1.27 \ $ and $ \ 3 + \sqrt3 \ \approx \ 4.73 \ \ , $ the larger of these being "to the right" of the interval $ \ (3 \ , \ 4 ) \ \ . $  Using larger integers simply shifts the vertex "lower and to the right", making the larger of the roots *even larger*.  Thus, we  confirm **Z Ahmed**'s conclusion that *there are no possible integer values of $ \ m \ $ to sum.*  (Trick question...)